# Resultado Web Service RETROFIT em Outra Activity - Android

Tags: android, web-service, retrofit

Possuo um método Web Service utilizando a biblioteca Retrofit que pode ser consultada à partir de 2 Activities diferentes.

Como posso utilizar o resultado do método Web Service que está em uma classe e mostrar em tela em uma Activity?

Como posso também atualizar um `ListView`, sendo que utilizo uma classe central com o método Retrofit, e ao ter o resultado do web service, a lista na Activity é atualizada?

Tentei várias vezes, requisitando um `return` da classe central com o método Retrofit, porém este retorno não acontece.

O que devo fazer?
Segue um trecho de meu código:

Chamo o método de consulta Web Service em uma Activity e espero um retorno para mostrar o resultado no TextView.

```
btnAtualizaEstoque.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    if (verificaConexao()) {

                       new RegrasWebServiceRetrofitHelper().buscaEstoqueOnLine(getActivity(), pro.codpro, pro.codder);

                       tvEstoqueAtual.setText(
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
```

Segue abaixo o método que está na classe RegrasWebServiceRetrofitHelper:

```
public int buscaEstoqueOnLine(final Activity activity, String codpro, String codder) {
        this.context = activity;
        this.activity = activity;

        final int[] quantidade = new int[1];

        Log.e("Incio requisicao", "Estoque Online");

        String select = "SELECT (QTDEST-QTDRES) QTDEST FROM E210EST WHERE CODPRO= '" + codpro + "' AND CODDER = '" + codder + "' AND CODDEP = '1'";

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Estoque.class, new EstoqueDeserialize()).setLenient().create();
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(setURL_GET())
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
        Call<List<Estoque>> request = service.estoqueOnLine(senha, select);

        request.enqueue(new Callback<List<Estoque>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Estoque>> call, Response<List<Estoque>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Erro Response: " + response.code());
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao sincronizar Validade Estoque! " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.e("Final requisicao", "ValidadeEstoque");
                    Log.e("Incio insert", "ValidadeEstoque");

                    List<Estoque> retornoEstoque = response.body();
                    for (int n = 0; n < retornoEstoque.size(); n++) {
                        quantidade[0] = retornoEstoque.get(n).qtdest;
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Estoque>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Erro Failure: " + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao sincronizar Validade Estoque! " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return quantidade[0];
    }
```

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `enqueue()` do Retrofit aceita um `Callback` que é exectado de forma assíncrona depois que a requisição é feita e convertida.

Você pode simplesmente passar o `Callback` como parâmetro para seu método `buscaEstoqueOnLine`

```
btnAtualizaEstoque.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    if (verificaConexao()) {

                       new RegrasWebServiceRetrofitHelper().buscaEstoqueOnLine(getActivity(), pro.codpro, pro.codder,
                       new Callback<List<Estoque>>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onResponse(Call<List<Estoque>> call, Response<List<Estoque>> response) {
                               if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                   Log.e(TAG, "Erro Response: " + response.code());
                                   Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao sincronizar Validade Estoque! " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 } else {
                                   Log.e("Final requisicao", "ValidadeEstoque");
                                   Log.e("Incio insert", "ValidadeEstoque");

                               }

                               // Fazer algo com a respota
                               tvEstoqueAtual.setText(???)
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onFailure(Call<List<Estoque>> call, Throwable t) {
                               Log.e(TAG, "Erro Failure: " + t.getMessage());
                               Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao sincronizar Validade Estoque! " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       });
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
```

E no método `buscaEstoqueOnLine`:

```
public void buscaEstoqueOnLine(final Activity activity, String codpro, String codder,
    Callback<List<Estoque>> callback) {
        this.context = activity;
        this.activity = activity;

        Log.e("Incio requisicao", "Estoque Online");

        String select = "SELECT (QTDEST-QTDRES) QTDEST FROM E210EST WHERE CODPRO= '" + codpro + "' AND CODDER = '" + codder + "' AND CODDEP = '1'";

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Estoque.class, new EstoqueDeserialize()).setLenient().create();
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(setURL_GET())
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
        Call<List<Estoque>> request = service.estoqueOnLine(senha, select);
        request.enqueue(callback);
}
```

---

Uma dica: Criar instâncias do Gson, OkHttp e Retrofit toda fez que fizer a requisições, assim como você está fazendo, não é a forma recomendada.

O ideal é criá-los uma única vez e reutilizá-los.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, muito obrigado pela dica.  Vou implementar suas sugestão e posto o resultado depois.  Abraços

Comment: Leonardo, o método 'Callback' funcionou perfeitamente.  Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.  Quanto as questões de criar instâncias do 'Gson', 'OkHttp' e 'Retrofit', como seria o melhor método para fazer esta requisição uma unica vez, sendo que, como você vê, preciso fazer um Deserialize.  Sua ajuda me ajudaria pois faço de uma só vez mais ou menos requisições, uma atráz da outra.  Desde já agradeço.

Comment: A requisição pode (em alguns casos deve) ser feita várias vezes. Estava me referindo a criação das variáveis Gson, Retrofit e OkHttp. A forma mais simples é criar um Singleton para armazená-las e reutilizá-las. Neste link tem alguns exemplos. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41672999